# Role playing a character that speaks in rhyme, and making it work well

Tags: pathfinder-1e, roleplaying

Pushing my gestalt game (the one that a lot of my questions are based on) to the back burner. I decided to create a hedge witch and be the healer of the group when I get us to our first game. I decided I wanted to have her speak in rhymes. It will be a common part of speech pattern. I think I'm decent at rhyming, but I don't know how easily I could rhyme consistently and often.

How do I make this work without annoying the others or making my role playing too difficult?

Answer (score 23):

**This will get gimmicky and old pretty fast if you're not careful, and you run the risk of burnout.**

That said, there are some ways to make it work.

- Pre-plan a few lines you know will get used.
- Prepare some fairly generic rhyming words you can use in a pinch to put a few lines together.
- Do not solely use couplets!  Mix up your rhyme scheme with limericks and other more-than-two-line rhymes.

Finally, and most importantly:  When a rhyme would be super-forced, you can't come up with anything, and/or you're a few sessions in and it's starting to get old:  **Describe the rhymes instead of saying them.**  This is a trick I suggest often to roleplayers, who tend to get stuck in a "RPing means I have to say everything my character says" mindset, which is entirely not true.

Instead of trying to find a fifth rhyming word for the name of the town you're traveling to, "[Character name] mentions that the stone bridge should be the right way.  [Bard and/or high-Linguistics character name] doesn't think the word she rhymed with Sandpoint is an exact rhyme, but it's probably not worth starting an argument over." works great.

> [Witch] uses a subtle double entrendre to remind the party that she's pretty much out of spells.  [Chaotic character] has to repress a smirk.

> The crone's face indicates intense concentration.  Either her *true seeing* spell has uncovered something very important, or she's still trying to find a word that rhymes with 'Urgathoa'.

And, of course, when she absolutely *must* break character:

> [Witch] sighs with resignation.  "Why the [expletive] [deity] does it have to be orange?"

Comment: "Anathema" rhymes with "Urgathoa".

Comment: Also note that remarks about whether things rhyme or not are inherently meta if you're following the common convention that your in-game language is rendered as English but isn't really English. Who says there's no rhyme for "orange" in Common? Of course the same applies to puns, and most authors and roleplayers don't worry about this, but for example J.R.R. Tolkien and Umberto Eco have both written in detail on the subject of translations in/of their work.

Comment: @SteveJessop It doesn't necessarily have to go meta, provided that your convention calls for contextual translation rather than literal translation (which avoids a lot of problems, not just this one), and provided that you are willing to hand-wave the translations working out smoothly and accurately to an unrealistic degree (again, avoids a lot of problems, not just this one). It just means that the translation transparently accounts for the differences in what rhymes.

Answer (score 1):

### This can work for a short campaign

We actually did this for a short D&D Ravenloft campaign we played over an extended weekend, back in the 2nd Edition days (so the answer here is not specific to Pathfinder, but I think the question really is neither, althoug it is tagged as such).

The DM had premade characters, and one of them was modeled after Rostand's [Cyrano of Bergerac](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrano_de_Bergerac_(Rostand)). I really would have enjoyed that character as I can rhyme reasonably well on the spot, too, but we drew lots of who will get which character and I ended up with a mundane thief instead that also was fun to play.

Cyrano ended up with a player who was not particularly strong at doing this, so he kept it to rather simple verses and did not manage to pull off a strong impression, but it still was OK and did not cause any problems. At least, nobody was annoyed by it.

I think one of the things that help here is that you are a whole group around the table, so unless this is a special discussion scene where you have to respond immediately, the player has enough time to work out how to put what they want to get across in rhyme form, while the other players speak their bit.

I'm not sure it would continue to be fun in a long-running campaign. In such a setting, you might prefer to have an out to not have to continue doing it (get a curse broken, atone, or something like that) when it gets old. But for a short one, it is fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is such a fun idea! I think you might increase the fun if you decrease the stress by making it a guide rather than a rule. Rhyme as often as you can, but don't sweat it when you can't.

I would look into articles on freestyle rapping, some people can come up with rhymes on the fly *so fast!* I am sure there are some tips there that would apply to you too.